# I want to show my own custom image instead of Font Awesome

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, css

I don't have much knowledge about JavaScript and jQuery. I need to some changes in website, I want to show my own custom image instead of fa fa map-maker. It is in header.php of my WordPress website.

Code is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    if(jQuery( window ).width() < 980 ){
      jQuery('.preview_submit_from_data .b_getdirection.getdir').html("<i class='fa fa-map-marker'></i>");
      jQuery('.preview_submit_from_data .b_getdirection.large_map').html("<i class='fa fa-retweet'></i>");
    }
    jQuery( window ).resize(function() {
      if(jQuery( window ).width() < 980 ){
        jQuery('.preview_submit_from_data .b_getdirection.getdir').html("<i class='fa fa-map-marker'></i>");
        jQuery('.preview_submit_from_data .b_getdirection.large_map').html("<i class='fa fa-retweet'></i>");
      }
    });

  });

</script>


.html( " class=fa fa-map-marker> </i>
```

I want to chang fa fa map-maker to myimage.png

Comment: The piece of code `.html( " class=fa fa-map-marker> </i>` looks like it is in the wrong place, and unfinished (no closing quote, bracket or semi-colon). It is also not inside the `<script>` tag. What is it intended to do?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="myimage.png" alt="my image"/>
```

put that instead of that lines

```
<i class='fa fa-map-marker'></i>
```